# Do not send data to the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to send data to my database but it has a problem

```
router.post('/insertInfo', function(req, res, next) {
    var info = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('infoUser').insertOne(info, function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Infomation inserted');
            db.close();
        })
    })
    res.redirect('/error');
});
```

Error results

Comment: You forgot the error results

Comment: Can you show error log? or screen?

Comment: `res.send('called');` instead of `res.redirect('/error');`